# jboss 7 deploy 2 jars : one sharing other

Tags: java, jar, jboss7.x, pom.xml

I have 2 maven projects ProjectA and ProjectB.
pom.xml in ProjectA has dependency of ProjectB and uses classes from there.
After mvn install i copy both .jar files into standalone/deployments in jboss7 and run ./standalone.sh. The exception is ClassNotFoundException and deploying fail.

pom.xml of ProjectA
`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.duracel</groupId>
<artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.duracel</groupId>
        <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`

pom.xml of ProjectB
`

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.duracel</groupId>
<artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

`

both surronded by `<project>` tags ofcorz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every artifact deployed in JBoss has his own classloader. From your question it is not clear what you want to do or what is inside the jar files. In general cases web applications are deployed as war or as ear file. Both can contain different jar files and share one classloader. If project b contain only some until classes than you can optionally install it as a module. For more information about modules have a look here [jboss modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html)

Comment: in projectA i have stateless bean with local interface and remote interface which is located in projectB

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a ClassNotFound because projectA can´t find the interfaces it implement's, which are located in another jar. To fix this, make an ear project, put projectA in the root of the ear, and put projectB in the lib folder of your ear.

As hertog says, you could also declare projectB as a module (it would behave like a shared lib)